# More than one Partitioner in a Spring batch job

Tags: spring-batch, partitioning

I have two different files(both are different layouts) which i am splitting it as multiple files to make use of local step partitioning.

so far i am handling with one file and i have created one custom partitioner class to make use of step partitioning.

Now i want to include another file, so i am planning to create another partitioner class for this new file. (Idea is to create another step for new file). Or can we use the same Partitioner for both steps?

Will this work or we need to create separate job for each files?

**This is my current configuration:**

```
<batch:step id="step9">
        <batch:partition step="loadFlatFiles" partitioner="multiFileResourcePartitioner">
                    <batch:handler grid-size="15" task-executor="loadCustomerTaskExecutor" />
        </batch:partition>
    </batch:step>

<bean id="multiFileResourcePartitioner" class="com.cdi.batch.partitioner.MultiFileResourcePartitioner"
        scope="step">
        <property name="keyName" value="fileResource" />
        <property name="fileName" value="fileName" />
        <property name="directory" value="file:${input.files.location}" />
</bean>
```

Please do let me know if this approach is correct and is there any problems will happen in this approach?

Regards,
Shankar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there should work fine.  Since the partitioner is step scoped, each step should get it's own instance.

Comment: Thanks @Michael..Do you mean to say i can use the same partitioner in both step? And also both files will be there in the same path.. in this case will it work? How do we pass different files to the partitioner if i use single partitioner for both steps?

Comment: If i have files in different location also how do we pass different files in each step to same partitioner?

Comment: In theory you could.  However it depends on your use case.  If you have different file locations, it's probably just easier to have the extra `Partitioner` instance.